# How to make a call to Web API HTTPS endpoint using ESP32-S3

Tags: c, arduino, esp32, arduino-esp32

I'm using [LILYGO T-Display-S3 ESP32-S3](https://www.lilygo.cc/products/t-display-s3) with [PlatformIO](https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/boards/espressif32/lilygo-t-display-s3.html) IDE.

I'm trying to write a bit of code that calls a Web API endpoint to retrieve and parse some JSON data. No luck when making a call to an HTTPS endpoint, any suggestions on why and what library(ies) I should use?

I have successfully managed to make HTTP calls to dummy endpoints but calling https just returns code -2 or -3.
The other problem I'm not sure which library to use, there seems to be *HTTPClient.h* and *HttpClient.h*. I ended up opting in for *ArduinoHttpClient.h* library, here's what Ive got so far:

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <ArduinoHttpClient.h>

WiFiClient wifiClient;
HttpClient client = HttpClient(wifiClient, "https://httpbin.org", 443);

void setup()
{
   // WiFi set up happens here
}

void loop()
{
   client.beginRequest();
   client.get("/get");
   client.sendHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
   client.endRequest();

   int statusCode = client.responseStatusCode();
   String responseBody = client.responseBody();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've also scratched my head the first time I had to deal with https :-)
Eventually I've settled on the WiFiClientSecure.h library directly from Espressif and it works well.

It can be a bit involved with the https, if you want it fully implemented you need to include the server's certificate in your code but there is also an "insecure" option where you don't bother checking the server's certificate but rather explicitly trust that the server URI you are sending the request is safe (for example if it's your own server).

The "insecure" option doesn't mean un-encrypted communication but rather skips the check of the server's certificate and may be easier to start with for a quick proof of concept (or may be the only way in some cases)

In summary, the connection will end up encrypted whichever way you use.

Here we go, I've found the link for the library and there are easy to follow examples

https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/tree/master/libraries/WiFiClientSecure

Hope this helps